# Is the direction of a bullet along the line of the bore when it just reaches or leaves the muzzle?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, projectile

Is the direction of a bullet along the line of the bore when it just reaches or leaves the muzzle? In doing a general physics problem, I meet the term "muzzle speed". In the problem it seems that the muzzle velocity is assumed to be along the bore but why is it so? Can the muzzle velocity direciton deviate from the line of the bore?

Comment: *"In the problem [...]"* Which problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bullet is confined to the line along the bore during its travel through the barrel.  Thus, by conservation of momentum, it will continue along this line unless a force perturbs it from this equilibrium.  This force, by necessity, must have a component that is not down the bore.

For most intents and purposes, there are no such forces, and a bullet leaving the gun travels along the boresight.  If one wishes to get pedantic, and enter the realm of nanosecond scale studies, there are going to be imperfections, such as metalic deformations or uneven pressures on the back of the bullet as it leaves the barrel which will cause it to deviate.  The fact that skilled shooters can hit the bullseye reliably tells you that this effect is very minor.  Indeed, I would argue it would be a major fundamental design goal of firearms for this deviation to be small compared to other sources of error.

After it has left the barrel, gravity and aerodynamic forces will move it off of this boresight path.  Bullets are designed such that these effects are predictable and can be accounted for before the shot is fired.

Comment: If the gun is moving during the shot, the the velocity of the bullet relative to the ground will be its velocity relative to the gun plus the velocity of the gun.